# android : draw pixels using opengl es

Tags: android, opengl-es, pixel

I'm trying to draw many pixels with opengl. but there is no such pixel method...(did i missing?)

exactly, i want to draw array of color data(like [0xff0000, 0xff00ff, ...], about 480*800) in renderer. (also refresh every frame)

if this is impossible how can i draw pixels?.... canvas can do it? but canvas is too slow i think... is there any way to draw many pixels?

i did use `glDrawElements()`, but only one pixel was draw...(at center of screen)

```
   int[] bitmapData = new int[480 * 800];

   public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
      ...
      // some processing of pixels
      ...

      buffer = IntBuffer.wrap(bitmapData);
      gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_POINTS, L, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, buffer);
   }
```

I thought, texture can contain bitmap(using GLUtils.texImage2D), so draw at texture and draw textrue at gl? but isn't overhead?

(sorry,, poor english)

Comment: Unfortunately this is somewhat undoable in a feasible way, AFAIK, as OpenGL isn't exactly designed for rendering bitmaps in this fashion. You might want to check ``Bitmap.getPixels(...)`` and ``Bitmap.setPixels(...)`` instead.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?